# Firebase error with CORS when running on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

I am getting the following error when running my project.

> Failed to load
>   https://us-centralx-xxx.cloudfunctions.net/xxx:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

After reading many SO post, I found the following solution, where I need to add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` , `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` , and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

```
const HEADERS = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  'http://localhost:3000/',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With,content-type'
};
```

However, the error still persist. How can i solve this ?

**UPDATE**

```
exports.uploadFile = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');


    res.status(200).json({
        message: req.body
    });
});
```

Comment: This problem related to the backend server when you sending a pre-flight request the server should allow the request and response with headers. in your `nodejs` headers you need to allow `http://localhost:3000 orgin` to get an access.

Comment: This CORS error was very misleading. I got this problem when the client was mistakenly calling the function to a different region where the function didn't even exist. Once the client pointed to the correct region, no more CORS issue. We didn't have to code any `res.setHeader()` as suggested by your questions and by other answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Node.js server set the appropiate headers to allow controlled CORS requests:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  // arrayOfValidOrigins is an array of all the URL from where you want to allow 
  // to accept requests. In your case: ['http://localhost:3000'].
  // In case you want to accept requests from everywhere, set:
  // res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  if (arrayOfValidOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }

  // Here allow all the HTTP methods you want
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PUT,OPTIONS');
  // Here you allow the headers for the HTTP requests to your server
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  // Method to reference to the next Node.js function in your flow
  next();
});
```

Another option you have is to use the [Express.js CORS package](https://github.com/expressjs/cors) and configure it suitable to your needs.

Comment: I still get the same error. i have updated my post with the code I have. Can you please have a look.

Comment: I don't get why are you setting all the CORS directives inside the export of a function called `uploadFile` but if you are trying to do it by hand in each route endpoint you are going to waste a lot of time. I would advise you to set the CORS directives to your Node HTTP server / app and before the setting of the routes, in order to work properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
import * as cors from 'cors'

const corsHandler = cors({origin: true})

export const myFunc = functions.https.onRequest(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
   corsHandler(req, res, () => {
     // Do your work here
   })
)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This was the way I solved it

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and got this same error when I realised that I hadn't deployed the function to Firebase. Deploying it stopped the error. So silly, but not that hard to make the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check logs from the Firebase function. In my case, the Chrome Devtools was showing a CORS error:

```
"severity": "ERROR",
"message": "Error: No Firebase ID token was passed as a Bearer token 
in the Authorization header. Make sure you authorize your request by 
providing the following HTTP header: Authorization: Bearer <Firebase ID Token>
```

As the solution, missing the Barear token was the problem to be solved.

Be sure to check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around these CORS errors by adding the `Cloud Functions Invoker` Role to my functions via https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/

- I found instructions in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation):

> ## Authorize access with IAM
>
> You use Identity and Access Management (IAM) to authorize identities to perform administrative actions on your functions, like creating, updating, and deleting them. You add principals (the identities you wish to enable, usually a user or service account email) to the function and then grant those principals the appropriate IAM roles. These roles include permissions that define the actions they are allowed to do.
>
> ### Enabling access to a function
>
> You can control actions on a function by granting or restricting roles to individual identities through IAM.
>
> ### [Adding principals and granting roles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#adding_principals_and_granting_roles)
>
> 1. Go to the Google Cloud console
> 2. Click the checkbox next to the function in which you are interested.
> 3. Click **Permissions** at the top of the screen. The **Permissions** panel opens.
> 4. Click **Add principal**.
> 5. In the **New principals field**, enter one or more identities that need access to your function. This is usually a user or service account email.
> 6. Select a role (or roles) from the **Select a role** drop-down menu. The roles you select appear in the pane with a short description of the permissions they grant.
> 7. Click Save.

Note: In my case, the principal I added was `allAuthenticatedUsers`

Sources:

1. https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/395#issuecomment-605025572
2. https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/fsw405/firebase_cloud_functions_cors_policy_error/